# Recreate input folder tree for output of some analyses

Tags: python, tree

I am new to Python and, although having been reading and enjoying it so far, have ∂ experience, where ∂ → 0.

I have a folder tree and each folder at the bottom of the tree's branches contains many files. For me, this whole tree in the *input*.

I would to perform several steps of analysis (I believe these are irrelavant to this question), the results of which I would like to have returned in an identical tree to that of the input, called *output*.

I have two ideas:

1. Read through each folder recursively using [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and for each file to perform the analysis, and
2. Use a function such as [shutil.copytree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) and perform the analysis somewhere along the way. So actually, I do not want to COPY the tree at all, rather replicate it's structure but with new files. I thought this might be a kind of 'hack' as I do actually want to *use* each input file to create the output file, so instead of a `copy`command, I need an `analyse` command. The rest should remain unchanged as far as my imagination allows me to understand.

I have little experience with option 1 and zero experience with option 2.

For smaller trees up until now I have been hard-coding the paths, which has become too time-consuming at this point.

I have also seen more *mundane* ways, such as using `glob` to first find all the files I would like and work on them, but I don't know how this might help find a shortcut in recreating the input tree for my output.

My attempt at option 1 looks like this:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Volumes/Mac OS Drive/Data/input/'):
    # I have no actual need to print these, it just helps me see what is happening
    print root, "\n"        
    print dirs, "\n"
    # This is my actual work going on
    [analysis_function(name) for name in files]
```

however I fear this is going to be very slow, I would also like to do some kind of filtering on files too - for example the `.DS_Store` files created in mac trees are included in the results of the above. I would attempt to use the `fnmatch` module to filter only the files I want.

I have seen in the `copytree` function that it is possible to ignore files according to a pattern, which would be helpful, however I do not understand from the documentation where I could put my analysis function in on each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both options: you could provide your custom `copy_function` that performs analysis instead of the default `shutil.copy2`  to `shutil.copytree()` (it is a more of a hack) or you could use `os.walk()` to have a finer control over the process.

You don't need to create parent directories manually either way. `copytree()` creates the parent directories for you and `os.makedirs(root)` can create parent directories if you use `os.walk()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import fnmatch
import itertools
import os

ignore_dir = lambda d: d in ('.git', '.svn', '.hg')
src_dir = '/Volumes/Mac OS Drive/Data/input/' # source directory
dst_dir = '/path/to/destination/'        # destination directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for input_file in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.input"): # for each input file
        output_file = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + '.output'
        output_dir = os.path.join(dst_dir, root[len(src_dir):])
        if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir) # create destination directories 
        analyze(os.path.join(root, input_file), # perform analysis
                os.path.join(output_dir, output_file))

    # don't visit ignored subtrees
    dirs[:] = itertools.ifilterfalse(ignore_dir, dirs)
```

Comment: I have successfully implemented this, only having to make slight changes (specific to my model) - it works like a charm! Many thanks!